# How can I make Static Property evalute when called

Tags: java

Does Java only call a declared variable once when declared inline in a class?  How can I make it update whenever I call it?

https://ideone.com/3WUWyO

```
public class MyClass {

    private static int level = 0;

    private boolean levelInline = (10 <= level);
    private boolean levelFunction = less(10,level);


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        level = 10;


       if (levelInline) {
           System.out.println("Inline True");
       }

       if (levelFunction) {
           System.out.println("Function True");
       }


        levelInline = (10 <= level);

        if (levelInline) {
            System.out.println("InLine True");
        }

        if (levelFunction) {
           System.out.println("Function True");
       }


    }

    private static boolean less(int a, int b) {
        return (a <= b);
    }


}
```

I would expect each time I query `levelInLine` and `levelFunction`, for the relevant right expression to be evaluated again.  i.e. my expected out put would be:

```
Inline True
Function True
Inline True
Function True
```

What I'm trying to do, instead of this:

```
 int debugLevel = 0;
 int levelToDoX = 5;
 int levelToDoY = 8;
 int levelToDoZ = 10;
 boolean DoX = debugLevel >= levelToDoX;
 boolean DoY = debugLevel >= levelToDoY;
 boolean DoZ = debugLevel >= levelToDoZ;
```

Have this:

```
 int debugLevel = 0;
 boolean DoX = debugLevel >= 5;
 boolean DoY = debugLevel >= 8;
 boolean DoZ = debugLevel >= 10;
```

I'm trying to skip the step of having to maintain magic number in their own variable - I though it made more sense to just have the numbers directly with the boolean, thus making it a little neater and easier to maintain.

Comment: Could you clarify the requirement? What's the output you're trying to get?

Comment: I would expect all of the calls to be true.  i.e. each time I say `levelFunction`, it actually calls `less()` and does the calculation.  (I could be mistaken but I recall C# working this way.)

Comment: A `String` calls a function? not bloody likely.  I'm normally good at these games, but I can't even begin to guess what you actually mean by that or how it is embodied by your example.

Comment: You can define it in a function.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, I mean to be providing an example on where I'm used to this.  For example I might often use: `String HOME= FileSystemView().getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` - I was under the impression it calls this string each time I use `HOME`

Comment: @CeePlusPlus are you talking about the `Func` delegate here or expression bodied methods? can you specify the equivalent in C#?

Comment: @Mureinik I added a more concrete example of what I'm trying to clean at the end of the post

Comment: @Aominè I just tried it in C# and I'm wrong. It's been a while since i've used C#, it could be I assumed it worked due to the shortcuts with get/set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just not how Java variables work. Once you assigned a value to a variable (or member), it's just a value. It has no "memory" of how this value was calculated, and it won't be recalculated when you access it. If you want to recalculate the value, you should define a method:

```
private static boolean levelFunction() {
    return less(10, level);
}
```

and call it when needed:

```
if (levelFunction()) {
    System.out.println("Function True");
}
```

Comment: So be it.   Appreciate the why.

Answer (score 2):

You can approximate what you want using "functional interfaces" and lambdas

```
public static Function<Integer,Boolean> levelInline = (Integer level) -> 10 <= level;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int level = 5;
    System.out.println(levelInline.apply(level));

    level = 10;
    System.out.println(levelInline.apply(level));

}
```

This declares an anonymous type that implements a `Function` taking an `Integer` argument and returning a `Boolean`, implemented as a lambda.  You can then execute it when you want by invoking its `apply()` method.

Read up on "Functional Interface" and "lambda" in the Oracle Java tutorial.

As suggested by @Aominè (thank you)

```
public static IntPredicate levelInline = (int level) -> 10 <= level;
...
int level = 5;
System.out.println(levelInline.test(level));
```

Comment: this was my initial thought when I read the question. +1 and btw even better would be to use `public static IntPredicate levelInline = level -> 10 <= level;` given that the function always takes an integer and returns a boolean or `public static Predicate<Integer> levelInline = level -> 10 <= level;`.

Comment: `IntPredicate` removes the unnecessary overhead of boxing and unboxing compared to `Function<Integer,Boolean>` , though both do the job.

Answer (score 1):

the static in java is at the class level, which means they get evaluated when the class is loaded.

in your case, when the class loads, level is set to 0, and levelInLine = false, and levelFunction to false.  This will stay with these values until you change it.

Then the main() method is run, the first 2 if-statement will be skipped for reason above.

Then you change the levelInLine again, this time it will be set to true.

Thus, the next if-statement in line 38 will result in the printout.  But the next if-statement will not print since levelFunction will still be false at this moment.